# Solve the maximum of a trigonometric function without differentiation

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, maxima-minima

The problem is,
when $f(x) \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^2} 
$for $(x \in [0,\frac π2])$,

what is the maximum of $f(x)$？

Of course, we solve this problem with differentiation.
Specifically, to solve $f’(x)=0$.
The answer is $sqrt(3)/9$ when $x=π/6$

I am also searching for a solution using inequalities(e.g. AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz).

However, I can't having precisely applying inequalities.
This is Because, I think, $f(x)$ is not **symmetric**.

Would you mind to tell me how to solve this problem using inequality?

Comment: oh…Thank you Mr.Surb for pointing this out to me.I made a grave mistake.The question was about the maximum value, but I was mistakenly typed the minimum value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By AM-GM, we have
$$\left(\frac{\sin x\, \cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}\right)^2
= \frac{\sin x\cdot \sin x\cdot (1 - \sin x)}{(1 + \sin x)^3}
\le \frac{\frac{1}{27}[\sin x + \sin x + (1 - \sin x)]^3}{(1 + \sin x)^3} = \frac{1}{27}$$
which results in
$$\frac{\sin x\, \cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}\le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}.$$

Comment: What a nice solution!!
I would like to be able to come up with this too! Thanks Mr. River Li.

Comment: @ykk You are welcome.

Comment: Wonderful idea of squaring the expression!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple representation is  obtained observing that the denominator is a form of the $1+\cos(x)$, so translate by $-\pi/2$ and double the angle.

$$\frac{\sin \left(2 \left(2 x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)}{\left(\sin \left(2 x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+1\right)^2}=\tan ^3(x)-\tan (x)$$

But the function is not even by reflection at its maximum

$$(x\to x^3-x)[(x\to \tan x^3)[x]] $$

$$\tan \left(-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\left(y \to y^3-y\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: I'm having trouble following your reasoning.  Could you be a bit more explicit?  And what do you mean by your notation in lines 2 and 4?

Comment: First  sqrt[(1+cos(x))/2}=sin(x/2) , So change  cos to sin by a translation, and for simplicity, double the argument. 


The notations in line 3,4 are bought from Mathematica (or lambda-notation), using the map itself as function name, with argument bracket appended:  in f: x -> x^2   f is replaced by a pure function  Function (x, x ^2) or simply (#^2&) . You can calculate  (#2&)(something) inline. without permently introducing superfluous declaration of function names.